# How to print words that are not in the list

Tags: python, loops, iteration, sentiment-analysis, tweets

I have 2 files, the first one is a list of tweets. And the second one is a list of standard words which looks like this:

```
acoustics
acquaint
acquaintable
tbc....
```

I want to iterate through the list of tweets and print the words that are not found in the standard words list.

This is what I tried:

```
dk = open('wordslist.txt','r')
dlist = []
for x in dk.readlines():
    dlist.append(x.replace('\n',''))

dlist
```

```
length = len(tokenized_tweets)
for i in range(length):
    print(tokenized_tweets[i])
```

```
for x in range(len(tokenized_tweets)):
    if x[0] not in dlist:
        print(tokenized_tweets[x])
```

and I got this error : `'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Hint: You used the `range` function in your first `for` loop but not in the second one. Why?

Comment: in the first loop I wanted to know the range of he tweets and then use it for the second loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read and follow the error message then you'll figure out what the problem is.

In traceback you would see an arrow pointing to line `for x in (len(tokenized_tweets)):`. The error message says: `'int' object is not iterable`. What is your iterable in that `for` loop? `(len(tokenized_tweets))` Is this really an iterable? No it's an `int`. The output of `len()` is always an `int`(unless you overwrite it).

You supposed to pass the length of the `tokenized_tweetes` to the `range()` object. It *is* an iterable.

##### extra tip:

Since you're finding the words for every tweet, make a `set` out of your words. Set's membership testing is much more faster than list. (O(1) > O(n))

It also removes duplicates if there are any.

### Solution:

```py
with open("wordslist.txt") as f:
    words_list = {word.removesuffix("\n") for word in f}

with open("tweets.txt") as g:
    for tweete in g:
        for word in tweete.split():
            if word not in words_list:
                print(word)
```

Comment: I tried changing it to this: "for x in range(len(tokenized_tweets)):
    if x[0] not in dlist:
        print(tokenized_tweets[x])" but it still gives me an error: 'int' object is not subscriptable" Can you elaborate more about the set?

Comment: @ZulfiA if you look closely it's now a different exception. It talks about "subscription". You can't do `x[0]` when `x` is an`int`. Just like saying: `4[0]`

Comment: I tried converting he integer to string by doing: data = str(tokenized_tweets). but it still doesn't work and gives the same error

Comment: @ZulfiA I updated the answer with solution. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes this is what I'm looking for! thank you so much for your help! is there any way to make the output to be separated line by line like in a class list? and is there any repeated words if I use this code?

Comment: @ZulfiA Please accept this one and ask another question as these questions are not related to your actual problem.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this, you are missing out writing `range`

```py
for x in range(len(tokenized_tweets)):
    if x[0] not in dlist:
        print(tokenized_tweets[x])
```

Comment: tried it but it still gives an error message "'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: try to use `if x not in dlist:`